C++ Image color reduction error diffusion not working
I'm trying to implement the Floyd-Steinberg error diffusion algorithm as seen on this blog and plenty of other sources and I cannot figure out what's gone wrong with my code for the life of me.
The function is pasted below and supports color reduction without error diffusion, which works flawlessly.
data is the array that contains the image data and BYTE_BOUND is a macro defined as shown. I'm trying to color reduce to 8 colors and loops through via bitwise operations.
#define BYTE_BOUND(value) (value > 255 ? 255 : (value < 0 ? 0 : value))

Image& Image::color_reduce(bool error_diffusion) {
    double r_diff, g_diff, b_diff, a[] = {0, 0, 0};
    std::pair<double, double*> min(INFINITY, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            min.first = INFINITY;
            for (int color = 0; color < 8; color++) {
                r_diff = data[(i * w + j) * channels] - (((1 << 2) & color) ? 255 : 0);
                g_diff = data[(i * w + j) * channels + (uint8_t)fmin(1, channels - 1)] - (((1 << 1) & color) ? 255 : 0);
                b_diff = data[(i * w + j) * channels + (uint8_t)fmin(2, channels - 1)] - ((1 & color) ? 255 : 0);
                if (r_diff * r_diff + g_diff * g_diff + b_diff * b_diff < min.first) {
                    min.first = r_diff * r_diff + g_diff * g_diff + b_diff * b_diff;
                    min.second[0] = r_diff;
                    min.second[1] = g_diff;
                    min.second[2] = b_diff;
                }
            }
            data[(i * w + j) * channels] -= min.second[0];
            data[(i * w + j) * channels + (uint8_t)fmin(1, channels - 1)] -= min.second[1];
            data[(i * w + j) * channels + (uint8_t)fmin(2, channels - 1)] -= min.second[2];
            if (error_diffusion) {
                // Floyd-Steinberg Error Diffusion
                for (int c_cn = 0; c_cn < (int) fmin(3, channels); c_cn++) {

                    data[(i * w + (uint32_t)fmin(j + 1, w - 1)) * channels + c_cn] =
                        (uint8_t) BYTE_BOUND(data[(i * w + (uint32_t)fmin(j + 1, w - 1)) * channels] + 7/16.0 * min.second[c_cn]);

                    data[((uint32_t)fmin(i + 1, h - 1) * w + (uint32_t)fmin(j + 1, w - 1)) * channels + c_cn] =
                        (uint8_t) BYTE_BOUND( data[((uint32_t)fmin(i + 1, h - 1) * w + (uint32_t)fmin(j + 1, w - 1)) * channels + c_cn] + 1/16.0 * min.second[c_cn]);

                    data[((uint32_t)fmin(i + 1, h - 1) * w + j) * channels + c_cn] =
                        (uint8_t) BYTE_BOUND(data[((uint32_t)fmin(i + 1, h - 1) * w + j) * channels + c_cn] + 5/16.0 * min.second[c_cn]);

                    data[((uint32_t)fmin(i + 1, h - 1) * w + (uint32_t)fmax(j - 1, 0)) * channels + c_cn] =
                        (uint8_t) BYTE_BOUND(data[((uint32_t)fmin(i + 1, h - 1) * w + (uint32_t)fmax(j - 1, 0)) * channels + c_cn] + 3/16.0 * min.second[c_cn]); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

Original Image

Color reduced without error diffusion

Color reduced with error diffusion.

I believe it works for greyscale images.



What is supposed to happen? What is the expected result? And start with a much smaller image, and use a debugger to step through the code to see what happens.

Here’s my suggestion: implement it first for single-channel gray-scale images. Once you get that working, adapt it to handle three channels instead of one. The three channels adds a lot of complexity that makes it harder to get the base idea implemented.

@CrisLuengo I believe it works for greyscale images. Original post updated.

That's unlikely because if channels is 1, then you're subtracting three errors from the one channel.

Also, since you're doing C++, please don't define a macro where you can define an inline function. When you do BYTE_BOUND(data[(i * w + (uint32_t)fmin(j + 1, w - 1)) * channels] + 7/16.0 * min.second[c_cn]), the data[(i * w + (uint32_t)fmin(j + 1, w - 1)) * channels] + 7/16.0 * min.second[c_cn] argument is evaluated two or three times by the macro! I think the operator presence is OK in this case, but I wouldn't rely on a macro that doesn't put parentheses around the argument. You do know that a macro is just textual replacement, right?

[cont.] The macro (if you're writing C) should be #define BYTE_BOUND(value) ((value) > 255 ? 255 : ((value) < 0 ? 0 : (value))), guarding  the use of value with parentheses. In C++ you should write this as template<typename T> T byte_bound(T value) { return value > 255 ? 255 : (value < 0 ? 0 : value); }. But you don't really need it to be generic here, just write a regular function that takes and returns a uint8_t.

@CrisLuengo Thanks for the suggestions on these points. You're totally right about both the bug for channels and possibility of the incorrect evaluation of the macro.

for more inspiration, browse the [tag:dithering] tag

Other things to look into are overflow/underflow of integer arithmetic (is data an array of 8-bit integers?) and improper rounding.

Oh, there's a + c_cn missing from the first line within the dithering loop. I would simplify those statements by computing the index once (int index = (i * w + (uint32_t)fmin(j + 1, w - 1)) * channels + c_cn), and then using that index (data[index] = (uint8_t) BYTE_BOUND(data[index] + 7/16.0 * min.second[c_cn]);).

One more comment: don't use fmin to compute the minimum of integers. fmin is specifically for float inputs. In C++ we have std::min, which is templated and works for any type. You won't need to cast its output.
